# AWS snapshot data backup to S3 and restore snapshot from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, snapshot, amazon-glacier

I had devised a strategy for ensuring the long-term protection of my AWS RDS MySQL database. The plan involved creating backups of the database and storing them in an S3 Glacier repository.

Initially, my approach was to generate manual snapshots through a Python Lambda function and subsequently save these snapshots to an S3 bucket. I intended to utilize lifecycle rules to transition the data from the S3 bucket to S3 Glacier. The process of exporting snapshots from the RDS to S3 functioned smoothly. During this export procedure, it was essential to specify the encryption key for security.

In order to verify the recoverability of the data, I attempted to restore a snapshot from S3 back to the RDS instance. However, this endeavor resulted in an error message indicating that restoration from an encrypted S3 object is not possible, as the files in the designated Amazon S3 bucket are encrypted.

While the export process mandates encryption, attempting to restore an encrypted snapshot to the RDS is unfeasible. This prompts the question of whether my current approach to backing up data by creating manual snapshots and pushing to the S3 bucket then to S3 Glacier is the correct methodology.

Could you kindly assess whether my chosen course of action for data backup and manual snapshot to S3 Glacier aligns with best practices?